# Select curve objects by extrusion profile object

Tags: objects, bevel, select

I need to select all curve objects in my scene that have their bevel geometry set to OBJECT and share the same “profile object” (bevel object):

bpy.context.object.data.bevel_object = bpy.data.objects["MY EXTRUSION OBJECT"]

Or do it in the “reversed” way - first select a curve object that is shared between multiple curve objects as their profile, and then select those objects.
Either of the above will satisfy me.

I guess that would be some simple script?
Can you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the second method that can be this script:

```
import bpy

# get the bevel object as the active one
bevel_object = bpy.context.active_object
# or get it by its name
#bevel_object = bpy.context.scene.objects["bevel object name"]

# loop over all objects in the scene
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    # select flag: 
    # a curve 
    # in object bevel mode 
    # that has the bevel object we want
    select = obj.type == 'CURVE' \
            and obj.data.bevel_mode == 'OBJECT' \
            and obj.data.bevel_object == bevel_object
    
    # select if yes / unselect if no
    obj.select_set(select)
```

For the first method, if you have several bevel objects in use the selection may mix everyone... so I don't think this is easier.

Comment: I dared to use my lack of coding skill and even simplified the code a little.
Anyway, thank you very much for your input. This is exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the slightly simplified version:

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    select = obj.type == 'CURVE' \
        and obj.data.bevel_mode == 'OBJECT' \
        and obj.data.bevel_object == bpy.context.active_object
    obj.select_set(select)
```

Comment: The "simplification" here is resigning from `bevel_object` name and just using its value directly in the following code, plus removing comments. If you really want to code golf the shit out of this, try `from bpy import context as C;for o in C.scene.objects:o.select_set(o.type=='CURVE'and o.data.bevel_mode=='BEVEL'and o.data.bevel_object==C.object)`